# How to ignore schema default value when querying in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

eg.

```
created: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    }
```

, but in mongodb there exists some old data without "created" field. How can I get real data but not Date.now.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) here to fetch the new documents which will have the created field.

Mongo Shell Query

```
db.collection.find( { created: { $exists: true} } )
```

Comment: I mean how can I only use default value when I use setters, but ignore that when I use getters.

Comment: You can add more filters to get your matching documents. If the requirement is to get the correct fields on created attribute then along with the filter `$exists:true`, you can add other filters.

Comment: Is there any way I can know whether the field has been changed by Default value ?